# Leibniz function in c

Tags: c, math, pi, approximation

I'm looking for a Leibniz approximation of PI in C.

I've tested this function but it does not seem to work:

```
float leibnizPi(float n){
    double pi=1.0;
    int i;
    int N;
    for (i=3, N=2*n+1; i<=N; i+=2)
        pi += ((i&2) ? -1.0 : 1.0) / i;
    return 4*pi;
}
```

Comment: I think the `&` should be `%` for modulo operation

Comment: What is your output? Show a [mcve].

Comment: @bhow `i` is always odd, so your suggestion would produce a constant one.

Comment: @That's right, my mistake. It seems I did not read through it carefully enough.

Comment: The `i&2` part is correct. That will be true for i=3, 7, 11,... but not 5, 9, 13.... Why is `n` a `float` when it's clearly just a count? Otherwise it looks fine. Why do think there's an error? In other words, what inputs are you giving it, what outputs do you get, and what do you think they should be?

Comment: I actually think this code works as shown.  It just takes many iterations for this formula to converge.  Try setting `n` to 1000000 and you will see it's pretty close to pi.

Comment: @TomKarzes.: Sorry for the hasty answer which ofcourse lead to errors. I didn't correlate with the leibnit'z expansion. Sorry for the inconvenience. Thanks for the criticism. I at first didnt get my fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tested you function and it seems to work fine. For `n=1000`, I get a result of `3.142592`.

How I've tested the function:

```
#include <stdio.h>

float leibnizPi(float n) {
    double pi=1.0;
    int i;
    int N;
    for (i=3, N=2*n+1; i<=N; i+=2)
        pi += ((i&2) ? -1.0 : 1.0) / i;
    return 4*pi;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("Pi: %f\n", leibnizPi(1000));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think this is right.  I tried it with `n=1000000` and it seems to converge, it just takes a lot of terms.

Answer (score 0):

OP's code interesting does its computation using `double` math and then after a potentially long loop returns a `float`.  Rather than truncate to a float.  Recommend to return a `double`.  With `float`, the result is not expected to be more accurate than 1 part in maybe 2<sup>23</sup>.

Belows shows that unnecessary impact which becomes evident after `n > about 100,000` and final about 600,000.

```
float leibnizPif(float n){
    double pi=1.0;
    int i;
    int N;
    for (i=3, N=2*n+1; i<=N; i+=2)
        pi += ((i&2) ? -1.0 : 1.0) / i;
    return 4*pi;
}

double leibnizPid(float n){
    double pi=1.0;
    int i;
    int N;
    for (i=3, N=2*n+1; i<=N; i+=2)
        pi += ((i&2) ? -1.0 : 1.0) / i;
    return 4*pi;
}

int main() {

  double pi = acos(-1);
  float f1 = pi;
  float f2 = nextafterf(pi, 0);
  printf("%e\n", f1-f2);
  printf("                     pi  %.12e\n", pi);
  for (unsigned i=1; i<29; i++) {
    unsigned n = 1u << i;
    float f = leibnizPif(n);
    double d = leibnizPid(n);
    printf("%9u f % .5e %.12e   ", n, (f-pi)/pi, f);
    printf("d % .5e %.12e\n",  (d-pi)/pi, d);

  }
  printf("                     pi  %.12e\n", acos(-1));
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
            error                pi
                     pi  3.141592653590e+00
        2 f  1.03474e-01 3.466666698456e+00   d  1.03474e-01 3.466666666667e+00
        4 f  6.30540e-02 3.339682579041e+00   d  6.30540e-02 3.339682539683e+00
        8 f  3.52602e-02 3.252365827560e+00   d  3.52602e-02 3.252365934719e+00
       16 f  1.87080e-02 3.200365543365e+00   d  1.87080e-02 3.200365515410e+00
       32 f  9.64357e-03 3.171888828278e+00   d  9.64354e-03 3.171888735237e+00
       64 f  4.89682e-03 3.156976461411e+00   d  4.89679e-03 3.156976358911e+00
      128 f  2.46747e-03 3.149344444275e+00   d  2.46748e-03 3.149344475125e+00
      256 f  1.23857e-03 3.145483732224e+00   d  1.23856e-03 3.145483689446e+00
      512 f  6.20513e-04 3.143542051315e+00   d  6.20487e-04 3.143541969477e+00
     1024 f  3.10574e-04 3.142568349838e+00   d  3.10546e-04 3.142568263114e+00
     2048 f  1.55377e-04 3.142080783844e+00   d  1.55349e-04 3.142080696509e+00
     4096 f  7.76643e-05 3.141836643219e+00   d  7.76934e-05 3.141836734621e+00
     8192 f  3.88840e-05 3.141714811325e+00   d  3.88514e-05 3.141714709002e+00
    16384 f  1.94559e-05 3.141653776169e+00   d  1.94269e-05 3.141653685021e+00
    32768 f  9.74187e-06 3.141623258591e+00   d  9.71375e-06 3.141623170237e+00
    65536 f  4.88485e-06 3.141607999802e+00   d  4.85695e-06 3.141607912146e+00
   131072 f  2.45634e-06 3.141600370407e+00   d  2.42849e-06 3.141600282926e+00
   262144 f  1.24208e-06 3.141596555710e+00   d  1.21425e-06 3.141596468272e+00
   524288 f  6.34955e-07 3.141594648361e+00   d  6.07127e-07 3.141594560935e+00
  1048576 f  3.31391e-07 3.141593694687e+00   d  3.03564e-07 3.141593607263e+00
  2097152 f  1.79610e-07 3.141593217850e+00   d  1.51782e-07 3.141593130427e+00
  4194304 f  1.03719e-07 3.141592979431e+00   d  7.58910e-08 3.141592892008e+00
  // No further improvement in float as precision is reached.
  8388608 f  2.78275e-08 3.141592741013e+00   d  3.79455e-08 3.141592772799e+00
 16777216 f  2.78275e-08 3.141592741013e+00   d  1.89728e-08 3.141592713194e+00
 33554432 f  2.78275e-08 3.141592741013e+00   d  9.48662e-09 3.141592683393e+00
 67108864 f  2.78275e-08 3.141592741013e+00   d  4.74328e-09 3.141592668491e+00
134217728 f  2.78275e-08 3.141592741013e+00   d  2.37136e-09 3.141592661040e+00
268435456 f  2.78275e-08 3.141592741013e+00   d  1.18567e-09 3.141592657315e+00
536870912 f  2.78275e-08 3.141592741013e+00   d  5.92798e-10 3.141592655452e+00
                     pi  3.141592653590e+00
                                              double keeps getting better
```

Modified code output

```
// with changes to use 64-bit integer math for the loops, 
// the result continue to get better returning double.
// It just takes longer and longer. 
1073741824 f  2.78275e-08 3.141592741013e+00   d  2.95864e-10 3.141592654519e+00
2147483648 f  2.78275e-08 3.141592741013e+00   d  1.47599e-10 3.141592654053e+00
4294967296 f  2.78275e-08 3.141592741013e+00   d  7.34476e-11 3.141592653821e+00
8589934592 f  2.78275e-08 3.141592741013e+00   d  3.63406e-11 3.141592653704e+00
```